# Jquery remove child elements that do not matches the number stored in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

and i have an html list

```
<ul>
  <li> list 1 </li>
  <li> list 2 </li>
  <li> list 3 </li>
  <li> list 4 </li>
  <li> list 5 </li>
  <li> list 6 </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to hide all the nth-child that do not match a number in my array.

Kind of like this:

```
if li:nth-child("number not in myArray").remove();
```

i can't seem to figure out who to loop properly, any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please mark one of answer as best to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate `li`s using `foreach` and check number of every `li` in it. If number of li doesn't exist in array, remove li.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 4, 5];

$("li").each(function(index){
    var liNum = $(this).text().match(/[\d]+/g)[0];

    if (myArray.indexOf(parseInt(liNum)) == -1)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> list 1 </li>
  <li> list 2 </li>
  <li> list 3 </li>
  <li> list 4 </li>
  <li> list 5 </li>
  <li> list 6 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This Gives an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.each` and `Array.prototype.indexOf` methods to accomplish the task:

```js
var array = [1, 3, 5, 7];
setTimeout(function() {
  var $list = $('.listToFilter li');
  $list.each(function(index, element) {
    if (array.indexOf(index) >= 0) {
      element.remove();
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>wait 1 second to see the items being removed:</p>
<ul class="listToFilter">
    <li>Item 0</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

You don't have to use `setTimeout`, I've used it just to make example a little more verbose.

Comment: It works, there's a 1 second timeout to get the items removed

Comment: This Gives an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: Well, no. Example works just fine. It's something in your code you're not telling us about in your question is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` and `indexOf` methods. :D

```
$("ul li").filter(function(){
    if([1, 2, 4, 5].indexOf($(this).index()+1)==-1)
    {return true;}
}).remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i should have added that i am getting the array dynamically based on a user input and the answers here so far gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

I solved my issue like this it may be a bit verbose but it does work so far:

```
$(#myimput).each( function () {

  var myField = $(this).text();
  var myFieldArray = ("" + myField).split("");
  var listItem = ":nth-child(";
  var listItemAssambled = "";
  var x;

  for (x in myFieldArray ) {
   listItemAssambled += listItem + myFieldArray[x] + "), ";
  }

  listItemAssambled = listItemAssambled.substring(0, listItemAssambled.lastIndexOf(','));

  if ($(this).text() >= 1) {
      $(#mylist li).not(listItemAssambled).remove();       
   }
});
```